# Combine two Tables in SQL. But what kind of join

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

```
1. Column1 Column2
   X       4
   Z       7

2. Column1 Column1
   Bed     Pizza
   Sun     Hamburger
```

Now I want to combine these two tables and the output table should look like this:

```
3. Column1_1 Column2_1 Column_1_2 Column_2_2
   X         4         Null       Null
   Z         7         Null       Null
   Null      Null      Bed        Pizza
   Null      Null      Sun        Hamburger
```

Comment: `union` allows you to append one table to the end of another table.  Your select for each table just has to make all the columns.

Comment: Why do you want to combine two completely unrelated tables?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah can you show me the select for it?

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is the JOIN you need.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired output simply *union* your tables and provide NULL value placeholders. Column names are taken from the *first* query in the union:

```
select column1 Column1_1, column2 column2_1, null Column_1_2, null column_2_2
from t1
union all
select null, null, Column1, Column2
from t2
```

Answer (score 0):

To achive what you are asking for, you may want to use one of the following:

CROSS JOIN (the easiest way to explain is: it returns all records from both tables)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table2 t2;
```

UNION (used for unique records) or UNION ALL (all records)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query to do this is not a join.

```
SELECT
Column1 Column1_1,
Column2 Column1_2,
null Column2_1,
null Column2_2
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
null,null,Columns,Columns
FROM table2;
```